# Unable to create Facebook App - Try again Later

Tags: facebook

I am unable to create a simple facebook app.  It continually says try again later.  I have searched the forums, but only see posts about people trying to create the app as a "page", but I am logged in as a "user" on the master account.  My account has been active for 7 years and I only have one page.

What do I have to do to get the ability to create an app?

I am simply trying to create the app so that customers can click a like button on our product pages.  This is done using a pre-built extension in the Magento E-Commerce platform.  All I need is the appID to plug into Magento.

Please help!

Comment: If you are having problems with Facebook, you will need to contact facebook: http://www.facebook.com/help

Comment: same here.. "try again later". And is not yet posted here http://www.facebook.com/KnownIssues

Comment: I've been trying for the past 30 minutes as well.  Same issue.

Comment: I just opened a different browser (not logged into Facebook) and tried to get to the Developer page https://developers.facebook.com/apps .  When I do that, I get asked to login, so it appears that every app has to be created by a specific logged in user.  I already have 1 app created years ago, but I can't create a new one.  Just thought this might help you realize that it appears, to me, that Facebook is broken, not you or me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today. I was trying to create an app for my fan page for this site: http://www.cutepickuplines.info

It looks like it's an issue with Facebook. I figure it will be resolved by the end of the day. I'll report back here when I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like things are working. If needed clear your browser cache or sign out before trying again.

Comment: this is working properly now.  It must have been down on Sunday.  Thanks to everyone who helped!